# I have integrated Google Analytic in my NextJs app. How Can I get all data from Google Analytic using axios to make my own Dashboard?

Tags: api, google-analytics, next.js

I am trying to make my own Dashboard using Google Analytics Data. Is there any Way to get all data from my integrated google api using axios or fetch in javascirpt ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is a way, here is the [Analytics Data API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1#node.js) and the [Node.js docs](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/analytics-data/latest/index.html)

and you can use any http client for Node.js, I personally use and recommend [Axios](https://github.com/axios/axios#axios).

*Please note that the Analytics Data API is an early preview version of the API and is subject to change.*

Comment: Can I add custom event in google analytics?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know this, you would need to go through the docs and see if there is an option for what you want to implement.